# Как выровнять изображение по центру блока и оставить его в "полном размере"?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть блок фиксированного размера

```
.item-img {
height: 255px;
width: 205px;
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;}
```

В этом блоке изображение (могут быть разных размеров) 
Нужно сделать что бы оно центрировалось и по горизонтали и по вертикали, и при этом оставалось пропорционально своим размерам
Как такое сотворить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом примере я изображение заменил на div. Но если убрать размеры и вставить картинку, то тоже сработает.

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 160px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <div class='image'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Пробуйте так.
Результат тут http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyYrbp

```
<div class='block'>
  <img class="image" src="http://ftimes.ru/upkeep/uploads/2015/12/Google.jpg">
</div>

.block {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало и с предыдущим ответом, просто я туплю, просмотрел, что в html были размеры дописаны -_-